# Online IDE to run the following scala code

Tags: scala

I want to test the following scala code. I want to use an online editor. I tried `scalafiddle` and `jdoodle` but both can't identify the work `package`. Is there an online IDE where I can run the following code?

```
package P {
  object X { val x = 1; val y = 2 }
}

package Q {
  object X { val x = true; val y = "" }
}


package P {                  // `X' bound by package clause
import Console._             // `println' bound by wildcard import
object A {
  println("L4: "+X)          // `X' refers to `P.X' here
  object B {
    import Q._               // `X' bound by wildcard import
    println("L7: "+X)        // `X' refers to `Q.X' here
    import X._               // `x' and `y' bound by wildcard import
    println("L8: "+x)        // `x' refers to `Q.X.x' here
    object C {
      val x = 3              // `x' bound by local definition
      println("L12: "+x)     // `x' refers to constant `3' here
      { import Q.X._         // `x' and `y' bound by wildcard import
//      println("L14: "+x)   // reference to `x' is ambiguous here
        import X.y           // `y' bound by explicit import
        println("L16: "+y)   // `y' refers to `Q.X.y' here
        { val x = "abc"      // `x' bound by local definition
          import P.X._       // `x' and `y' bound by wildcard import
//        println("L19: "+y) // reference to `y' is ambiguous here
          println("L20: "+x) // `x' refers to string "abc" here
}}}}}}
```

Comment: It works on Scastie well. Only disable the Worksheet mode in scastie

Comment: thank you. Opened a new question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56755847/how-can-an-example-have-two-packages-with-same-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scastie, try turning `Worksheet` mode OFF and then `extend App` to provide main method, for example, try pasting the following in Scastie:

```
package P {
  object X { val s = "hello"}
}
package P {
  object Y { val s = "world"}
}

object Hello extends App {
  println(P.X.s)
  println(P.Y.s)
}
```

Note that `P` and `Q` from your [example](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html) should be in separate compilations units

> Assume the following two definitions of objects named X in packages p
>   and q in *separate compilation units*.
>
> ```
> package p {   
>   object X { val x = 1; val y = 2 }
> }
>
> package q {   
>   object X { val x = true; val y = false } 
> }
> ```

which means they should be in separate `.scala` files. I am not sure it is possible to have multiple files in Scatstie.

Comment: Though I agree that w.r.t. the question asked, `scastie` is the right answer so I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Strange that the document from where I picked the example doesn't clearly say that P and Q are separate compilation units (https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html).

Comment: Ah you are looking at old Scala 2.11 documentation, try 2.13 docs.

Comment: thanks. Got it - https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html