# how can an example have two packages with same name

Tags: scala

Referring to the example at https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html, I notice that the `package P` is defined twice in the example. Isn't the example incorrect? I tried to run it in Scastie but the code doesn't compile.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZZ3vjsNzSvWnY1gFCqaNAg

```
    package P {
      object X { val x = 1; val y = 2 }
    }

    package Q {
      object X { val x = true; val y = "" }
    }
//    The following program illustrates different kinds of bindings and precedences between them.

//isn't this redefining P??    
    package P {                  // `X' bound by package clause
    import Console._             // `println' bound by wildcard import
    object A {
      println("L4: "+X)          // `X' refers to `P.X' here
      object B {
        import Q._               // `X' bound by wildcard import
        println("L7: "+X)        // `X' refers to `Q.X' here
        import X._               // `x' and `y' bound by wildcard import
        println("L8: "+x)        // `x' refers to `Q.X.x' here
        object C {
          val x = 3              // `x' bound by local definition
          println("L12: "+x)     // `x' refers to constant `3' here
          { import Q.X._         // `x' and `y' bound by wildcard import
    //      println("L14: "+x)   // reference to `x' is ambiguous here
            import X.y           // `y' bound by explicit import
            println("L16: "+y)   // `y' refers to `Q.X.y' here
            { val x = "abc"      // `x' bound by local definition
              import P.X._       // `x' and `y' bound by wildcard import
    //        println("L19: "+y) // reference to `y' is ambiguous here
              println("L20: "+x) // `x' refers to string "abc" here
    }}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not redefining, it is adding to package `P`, for example

```
package P {
  object X { val s = "hello"}
}
package P {
  object Y { val s = "world"}
}

object Hello extends App {
  println(P.X.s)
  println(P.Y.s)
}
```

outputs

```
hello
world
```

which means `X` and `Y` are now available from package `P`

Comment: Thanks Mario (as always!). Could you also please tell me why the code in scastie is showing errors? As it is an example from specifications, I expected that it will work